# Binding child width and height to parents makes it unable to become smaller when resizing

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview, resize

When I bind an `ImageView` to it's container:

```
imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(heightProperty());
```

It functions as intended when making the container bigger (the `imageview` scales accordingly), but when I try to make the container smaller, neither the container or the `imageview` becomes smaller. Strangely, when I set the imageview's image before the `stage.show()` method, it does function as intended, but again faces the same issue when changing the image after the `stage.show()` method.

Instead of bindings i've tried using listeners (both `ChangeListener` and `InvalidationListener`), changing the `layoutChildren()` method in the container/parent class and making a wrapperclass for the imageview, but they didn't solve the issue.

My project doesn't use FXML, so I would like to find a solution that doesn't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to shrink it, the container is (probably) going to remain large enough to hold the `ImageView` at its current size, and will be clipped by its container just to show the visible portion. Binding to dimensions is never a particularly good approach; to create custom layouts, subclass `Region` and override `layoutChildren()`.

Here is a quick example:

```
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;

public class ImageContainer extends Region {
    private final ImageView imageView ;

    public ImageContainer(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
        getChildren().add(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        // usable width and height:
        double width = getWidth() - snappedLeftInset() - snappedRightInset();
        double height = getHeight() - snappedTopInset() - snappedBottomInset();
        imageView.setFitWidth(Math.max(1, width));
        imageView.setFitHeight(Math.max(1, height));
        double imageWidth = imageView.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        double imageHeight = imageView.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
        // center image (can also make this more complex and support alignment):
        double x = snappedLeftInset() + (width - imageWidth) / 2;
        double y = snappedTopInset() + (height - imageHeight) / 2;
        imageView.relocate(x , y);
    }

}
```

and

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    private final String ioColor = "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA00738/PIA00738~orig.jpg";
    private final String ioBW = "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA01217/PIA01217~orig.jpg";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        ImageView leftImage = new ImageView(ioBW);
        leftImage.setPreserveRatio(true);
        ImageView rightImage = new ImageView(ioColor);
        rightImage.setPreserveRatio(true);
        SplitPane splitter = new SplitPane(new ImageContainer(leftImage), new ImageContainer(rightImage));
        Scene scene = new Scene(splitter, 800, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue in my project, probably due to bindings of other classes higher in the container hierarchy. The example provided by you does indeed work as intended, even when changing the image  after stage.show(). I will try to apply the same idea to the other classes that use binding to determine their size and hope that solves the issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Acheros while binding can be used to help solve some layout problems, it is sometimes not the best way to handle layout.  When you look at the JavaFX library source code, most layout problems are solved through layoutChildren, not binding.  Such solutions aren’t widely demonstrated or documented outside the JavaFX code base and can be tricky to implement.  Usually it is best to let combinations of inbuilt layout panes handle layout, falling back to custom layout using layout children overrides (or very carefully binding), only when necessary.