# Changing scale for ImageView

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I have a problem with setting scaleX on `ImageView`. Here is a part of my code:

```
    bgImage.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        double n = newValue.doubleValue() / 967;
        cover.setScaleX(n);
    });
```

Problem is that it doesn't work. I want to make resizable background when stage changes size.

Comment: *"I want to make resizable background when stage changes size."* -> You can do that in CSS without an `ImageView`, see [background images in the CSS reference](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region), and the sizing options provided by `-fx-background-size`.

Comment: If you do want to resize an image view, use `setFitWidth()` and `setFitHeight()`, which will use appropriate image rescaling algorithms. Simply using `scaleX` and `scaleY` may not give as good image quality. But the suggestion by @jewelsea is a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a listener for this.  Bind the ImageView’s [fitWidth](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#fitWidthProperty) and [fitHeight](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#fitHeightProperty) properties to its parent’s dimensions:

```
BorderPane imagePane = new BorderPane(bgImage);
bgImage.fitWidthProperty().bind(imagePane.widthProperty());
bgImage.fitHeightProperty().bind(imagePane.heightProperty());
```

Comment: I probably have some answers to questions on this site using approaches like this, but a while ago I came to the conclusion this is a bad idea. The problem is that the dimensions of a parent are always implicitly dependent on the dimensions of its children. This binding creates an explicit dependency of the dimensions of the child node on that of its parent. The library code is explicitly written to prevent things like infinite recursion, but weird things can still happen.

Comment: I think the more robust solutions are either to use a resizable pane with a background image (probably the simplest approach), as suggested by jewelsea’s comment, or to use a custom container for the `ImageView`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76557911/2189127)

Comment: @James_D Fair point, but I’m pretty sure there is no circularity because the fitWidth and fitHeight match the container, so the container observes dimensions which are already equal to its own size and therefore do not constitute property changes for the container at all.  I agree that jewelsea’s approach of using a background is more reliable.

Comment: `fitWidth` and `fitHeight` don't necessarily match the container, though. For example, if you set non-zero padding on the container, the container will grow to hold the image view plus the padding, causing the image view to grow (via the binding), etc. You might think you can simply encapsulate this so there's no opportunity to change the padding, but padding is a styleable property (so it can be set via an external stylesheet). [Here is an example.](https://gist.github.com/james-d/08971a9d511727ea44d72917dec40e20)